# Joyent SmartOS: Installing NPM Packages

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, joyent

So I'm trying to host a node app with Joyent smartOS. After creating my instance, I git copied my current commit and tried to run `npm install`. The only problem is the process will get a little of the way through then fail.

Sifting through the logs, this seems the most relevant to me:

```
ERR!stack  Error: not found: make
```

I ran the package it fails on, `npm install jquery`, and I received the same fail error.

Does Joyent's node-based smartOS not have a `make` keyword? Is there anyway around this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default SmartOS image is lean, and doesn't include the "make" package.  You should be able to install it with "pkgin install gmake".

Comment: how to install pkgin?

Comment: pkgin is installed in /opt/local/bin in all SmartOS images.  (It's not present in global zones, if that's what you're wondering about.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a non-global zone, you need to do:

## pkgin install gmake-3.82nb5

...